# Meaning of "podrá requerirse"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In Spain, [Ley Orgánica 4/2000 de 11 de enero](https://www.boe.es/boe/dias/2000/01/12/pdfs/A01139-01150.pdf) contains the sentence,

> "En el procedimiento podrá requerirse la comparecencia personal del solicitante."

To me (and apparently to the *consulado*), that means I **will be** required to appear in person.  But Google Translate says "… may be …"

I like to think my Spanish is better than Google's, but I'd like to know what this group thinks about this one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the verb *can* is defective in English, it's hard to imagine what *poder* means outside if present or past (where *poder* generally translates to *can*'s old past tense, *could*).

Sometimes for other forms like the perfects (*he podido*, etc) or potentials (*podré*, *podría*), it can be easier to switch to English's periphrastic equivalent, *to be able*. When used impersonally and in the present/past it would translate better with the pair of also-defective verbs *may/might*, it tends to make more sense as *to be possible* or as the adverb *possibly* with the other verb placed in the appropriate English tense.

In this light, we can see that this sentence says that the personal appearance *will possibly be required*. In English, we would simply render this, though, as *a personal appearance may<sub>(at such future time)</sub> be required*.

The consulate, of course, based on that law is free to require it, but may if it chooses, opt not to require it.

Comment: Thanks.  The consulate website states it as an absolute requirement, but some people have said they got theirs without appearing in person.

Comment: @WGroleau it will depend on the consulate, and of course it's their discretion to make exceptions (if the law strictly obligated it, they couldn't make any exceptions). If this is for a visa, I can probably attest to having been allowed to do things via mail rather than the normal in person.

Comment: Yes, visa.  What a bureaucratic nuisance.  Sounds like you might have some insight into https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/11220/583

Comment: P.S. Since I knew 'poder' as 'to be able to,' it must have been a senior moment for me to translate it as 'will'!  :-)

Comment: There's the objective meaning of the expression, and then there's the burocrat's interpretation.

Answer (score 2):

If you had to translate "*En el procedimiento **se requerirá** la comparecencia (...)*", what would you translate it to?

You'd probably say "**will be**", too.
But the two sentences have clearly different meanings, so that cannot be right, can it?

As a reference, these are the correct tenses:

- Sure future action: **se requerirá** --> ***will be required***
- Probable future action: **podrá requerirse** --> ***may be required***
- Possible future action: **podría requerirse** --> ***might be required***

Comment: Yes, as I commented above, I made a ridiculous mistranslation of "poder"